# How log my score best out of three and use different symbols for the players? Python

Tags: python

I'm making a 2-play Battleship game in python and have been struggling with this for a while now:

I apologise if the question is poorly worded but I was to know how I can make my game log the match score at the end of the three games with something like:

```
print('Match score is' + score + 'Player' + (whoever) + 'wins!)
```

I'm not entirely sure how to implement this myself I have a range `for games in range(3)`, but I don't know how to log the final score.

Also, how can I change the symbol for player_two so that I am not using an 'X' for both players? I've tried changing the `input_check()` but I get more errors than I did before.

```
from random import randint

game_board = []
player_one = {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}
player_two = {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}


# Building our 5 x 5 board
def build_game_board(board):
    for item in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

def show_board(board):
    print("Find and sink the ship!")
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

# Defining ships locations
def load_game(board):
    print("WELCOME TO BATTLESHIP!")
    print("START")
    del board[:]
    build_game_board(board)
    show_board(board)
    ship_col = randint(1, len(board))
    ship_row = randint(1, len(board[0]))
    return {
        'ship_col': ship_col,
        'ship_row': ship_row,
    }

ship_points = load_game(game_board)


# Players will alternate turns.
def player_turns(total_turns):

    if total_turns % 2 == 0:
        total_turns += 1
        return player_one

    else:
        return player_two

# Allows new game to start
def play_again():
    global ship_points
    answer = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    if answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
        ship_points = load_game(game_board)

    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()

# What will be done with players guesses
def input_check(ship_row, ship_col, player, board):
    guess_col = 0
    guess_row = 0
    while True:
        try:
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:")) - 1
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:")) - 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number only: ")
            continue
        else:
            break
    match = guess_row == ship_row - 1 and guess_col == ship_col - 1
    not_on_game_board = (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4)

    if match:
        player["wins"] += 1
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        play_again()

    elif not match:
        if not_on_game_board:
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

        elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X":
            print("You guessed that one already.")

        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        show_board(game_board)

    else:
        return 0


def main():
    begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')
    while (begin != str('start')):
        begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')

    for games in range(3):
        for turns in range(6):

            if player_turns(turns) == player_one:
                # print(ship_points)
                print("Player One")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_one, game_board
                )

            elif player_turns(turns) == player_two:
                print("Player Two")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_two, game_board
                )

        if turns == 5:
            print("The game is a draw")
            play_again()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style string formatting to print the log.

```
print('Match score is %d : %d(Player1 : Player2)' % (player_one["wins"], player_two["wins"]))
```

For more information about string formatting, check [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

To change the symbol for Player 2, you can change the following code.

```
elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X" or board[guess_row][guess_col] == "Y":
    print("You guessed that one already.")

else:
    print("You missed my battleship!")
    if player == player_one:
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    else:
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "Y"
```

Comment: @zalidael You are welcome. You can click the tick beside my answer to accept it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the link as well, very informative.

Comment: Small possible bit of code tidying: we could have a variable called cur_player which switches from one to zero, and then player_misses = ['X', 'Y'] and board[guess_row][guess_col] = player_misses[cur_player]. Then the first elif would say elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == player_missees[cur_player].